# Drop production database Capistrano & PostgreSQL || RAILS 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I'm using **RAILS 5** and want to drop create & migrate my current production app, but how can I do this with **Capistrano**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this gem [Capistrano-rails-collection](https://github.com/dei79/capistrano-rails-collection)

Comment: Thank you! Worked